# Magento 2 Module upgrade error

Tags: magento2

Why im facing upgrade error issue all of a sudden.

Im getting as below:

[image]

1) I run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

2) cleared all cache

3) run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

4) Gave full write permission to my project folder.

Post all these, still im getting the same error in screen.

Comment: Have you upgrade your magento set up ?

Comment: yes its the latest release taken from the community

Answer (score 2):

Check `setup_module` table and change all module current version with a required version that you have added in the question image.

or

Remove all module from `setup_module` and then follow below steps

1. run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command
2. run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**
3. Cleared all cache
4. run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
5. Gave full write permission to my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all third party extensions then try

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```